# Azure Function access to SQL Server -IAAS through managed identity

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, sql-server-2019, azure-managed-identity, iaas

I have an Azure function and a user assigned managed identity. I would like to connect a SQL Server hosted on Azure VM.

But the problem is `CREATE USER/CREATE LOGIN [mymangedIdentity] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` clause is not supported for Azure AD authentication on SQL Server hosted on Azure VMs. It only works in Azure SQL and Azure MI.

Answer (score 0):

Entra ID (AAD) Auth for SQL Server is a SQL Server 2022 feature.

> SQL Server 2022 (16.x) introduces support for authentication with Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory), on both Windows and Linux on-premises, and SQL Server on Windows Azure VMs.

[Microsoft Entra authentication for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, mine is SQL Server 2019(15.X). So, in that case, is it possible?

Comment: No.  Entra ID auth is SQL Server 2022 feature.